# Sierpinski Triangle in AEC

Tags: fractals, compiler

So, I've tried to extend my [compiler](https://flatassembler.github.io/compiler.html) so that it can target GNU Assembler. And I've made a simple program to demonstrate that.

```
Syntax GAS
;So, this is an example of how to target GNU Assembler (GAS) using AEC, and how to target Linux.
AsmStart ;What follows is the assembly code produced by CLANG 9.0 on Linux, I don't understand it either, and it's not important.
    .text
    .file   "sierpinski.c"
    .globl  main                    # -- Begin function main
    .p2align    4, 0x90
    .type   main,@function
main:                                   # @main
# %bb.0:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    subl    $24, %esp
    movl    $0, -4(%ebp)
    leal    .L.str, %eax
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    calll   printf
    leal    .L.str.1, %ecx
    movl    %ecx, (%esp)
    leal    n, %ecx
    movl    %ecx, 4(%esp)
    movl    %eax, -8(%ebp)          # 4-byte Spill
    calll   __isoc99_scanf
AsmEnd ;And here goes a program written in AEC, finally.
i:=0
While i<n ;This loop will fill the array "new_array" with zeros, except the point right in the middle, which will be filled with 1.
    If i=n/2-mod(n/2,1) ;So, if i=floor(n/2), except that I didn't put "floor" in my programming language, so I need to paraphrase it.
        new_array(i):=1
    Else
        new_array(i):=0
    EndIf
    i:=i+1
EndWhile
i:=0
While i<n
    j:=0
    While j<n | j=n ;Printing the current state and the new line.
        If j=n
            AsmStart
                .intel_syntax noprefix #Because I don't know anything about att_syntax assembly.
                mov byte ptr [esp+4],'\n' #'\n' is, of course, the new line character (in FlatAssembler, you would need to write 10, the ASCII of '\n').
                .att_syntax #Not important here (my compiler switches to Intel Syntax before outputting anything except inline Assembly), but added for consistency.
            AsmEnd
        ElseIf new_array(j)=1
            AsmStart
                .intel_syntax noprefix
                mov byte ptr [esp+4],'*'
                .att_syntax
            AsmEnd
        Else
            AsmStart
                .intel_syntax noprefix
                mov byte ptr [esp+4],' '
                .att_syntax
            AsmEnd
        EndIf
        charSign<="%c\0" ;If you write "'%c',0", as you write that in FlatAssembler, GAS complains.
        AsmStart
            .intel_syntax noprefix
            lea ebx,dword ptr [charSign]
            mov dword ptr [esp],ebx
            call printf
            .att_syntax
        AsmEnd
        j:=j+1
    EndWhile
    j:=0
    While j<n ;Copying "new_array" into "old_array".
        old_array(j):=new_array(j)
        j:=j+1
    EndWhile
    j:=0
    While j<n
        If j=0 | j=n-1 ;Edges
            new_array(j):=0
        ElseIf old_array(j-1)=old_array(j+1) ;In other words, each cell in the new line in the Sierpinski triangle is the "xor" of its neighbours in the line above it.
            new_array(j):=0
        Else
            new_array(j):=1
        EndIf
        j:=j+1
    EndWhile
    i:=i+1
EndWhile
AsmStart ;Again, assembly code produced by CLANG 9.0 on Linux, I don't understand it either.
    xorl    %ecx, %ecx
    movl    %eax, -12(%ebp)         # 4-byte Spill
    movl    %ecx, %eax
    addl    $24, %esp
    popl    %ebp
    retl
.Lfunc_end0:
    .size   main, .Lfunc_end0-main
                                        # -- End function
    .type   .L.str,@object          # @.str
    .section    .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1
.L.str:
    .asciz  "Enter the number of rows and columns in the Sierpinski triangle.\n"
    .size   .L.str, 67

    .type   .L.str.1,@object        # @.str.1
.L.str.1:
    .asciz  "%f"
    .size   .L.str.1, 3
    .type   n,@object               # @n
    .comm   n,4,4
    .type   i,@object               # @i
    .comm   i,4,4
    .type   j,@object               # @j
    .comm   j,4,4
    .type   result,@object          # @result
    .comm   result,4,4
    .type   old_array,@object       # @old_array
    .comm   old_array,320,4
    .type   new_array,@object       # @new_array
    .comm   new_array,320,4

    .ident  "clang version 9.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_900/final)"
    .section    ".note.GNU-stack","",@progbits
    .addrsig
    .addrsig_sym printf
    .addrsig_sym __isoc99_scanf
    .addrsig_sym n
AsmEnd
```

The executable file is available [here](https://github.com/FlatAssembler/ArithmeticExpressionCompiler/raw/master/ArithmeticExpressionCompiler.zip), it's called `sierpinski.elf`.
So, what do you think about it?